# Selecting 6 teams out of 12 to make the playoffs, given each team has a different probability

Tags: python, statistics, probability, montecarlo

I'm trying to run a Monte Carlo simulation using Python to determine multiple playoff scenarios of teams in my fantasy football league. But I haven't gotten that deep into it yet as I'm stuck on the first step of the algorithm.

I've determined that the first thing I want to do in the algorithm is reliably pick the 6 playoff teams in a way that if repeated 10,000 times should pretty closesly line up with the probabilities I've assigned the teams.

For example, if I gave team A a probability of 78% to make the playoffs, I want my team selection algorithm to choose team A 7800 times out of 10,000 with a reasonable degree of error maybe +/- 1% so like 7700 - 7900 times out of 10,000.

The algorithm in english is basically:
"for every team in the league, choose a random percent (1-100 / 100) and compare it to the probability that the team makes the playoffs. If the die roll is less than or equal to the team's probability to make the playoffs, then add them to a list. If after running through all 12 teams, this list has a length of exactly 6, return the result. Otherwise clear the list, start over, and keep going until you have exactly 6".

Unfortunately the actual results I'm getting is that the teams above 50% in probability are ending up with slightly more playoff appearances and the teams under 50% in probability are ending up with slightly less playoff appearances. So the 33% team is regularly showing up 2800-2900 times (28-29%) but the team with a 68% probability is showing up regularly 7100-7200 times (71-72%)

If I remove the part of the code that checks if the list is an exact length of 6, and just allow lists of all lengths, the output becomes more in line with the probabilities and are within the 1% margin of error I'm looking for. But I need for this list to have an exact length of 6. So how do I get around this?

I am pretty new to Python, so be gentle :) Advice is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
import random

#List is (team abbreviation, playoff odds)
AA = ["AA",.33]
BG = ["BG",.99]
BSC = ["BSC",.68]
BT = ["BT",.95]
CHA = ["CHA",.97]
DDB = ["DDB",.11]
EJ = ["EJ",.48]
KCT = ["KCT",.82]
MTA = ["MTA",.00]
NSR = ["NSR",.01]
TDP = ["TDP",.57]
THR = ["THR",.09]
teams = [AA,BG,BSC,BT,CHA,DDB,EJ,KCT,MTA,NSR,TDP,THR]

# Algorithm to pick the 6 playoff teams
# Dice roll turned into a percentage and compared against each team's probability
# Throw out any results that don't have exactly 6 teams

def playoffs():
    while True:
        playoff_list = []
        for i in teams:
            diceroll = random.randint(1,100) / 100
            if i[1] >= diceroll:
                playoff_list.append(i[0])
            else:
                continue
        if len(playoff_list) == 6:
            break
        else:
            continue
    return playoff_list

# Function to run the above selection algorithm 10,000 times
# Add every 6-team scenario to one giant list with 60,000 items

def playoffs_check():
    playoff_teams = []
    playoff_test = 0
    while playoff_test < 10000:
        playoff_teams.extend(playoffs())
        playoff_test += 1
    return playoff_teams

# Run the algorithm
# Count the results so you can compare to the original probabilities

playoffs_list = playoffs_check()
for x in teams:
    print(x[0],playoffs_list.count(x[0]))
```